# Run a macro on each sheet except Sheet1 and Sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to run a macro on every sheet except sheet1 and sheet2.

```
    dim rs as worksheet  
for each rs in sheets  
    if rs.name = "Sheet1" or "Sheet2" then  
    next rs  
else rs.name =rs.range("
```

I get the error

> next without for

How can I use next the for loop and the if statement?

```vb
Dim rs As Worksheet
        
For Each rs In Sheets
    If rs.Name = "sheet1" Or "sheet2" Then
Next ws
    Else: rs.Name = rs.Range("N2") 'rename sheet base on vendor name field

    End If
Next rs
```

Comment: You changed variable name from rs to ws.  If you change that and remove the colon after Else it should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Small mixup, try :

```
Dim rs As Worksheet

For Each rs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   If rs.Name <> "Sheet1" And rs.Name <> "Sheet2" Then
        rs.Name = rs.Range("N2").Value 'rename sheet base on vendor name field
   End If
Next rs

End Sub
```